# CSS layout/display issue on Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have some text on a page that is not displaying at all. When I pull up dev tools on chrome, I can see that the data is there; it is just not being displayed. Potentially due to some CSS clashes?

Any pointers? The site is built on Wordpress.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a css class is putting a display: none !important style on it that's preventing the text from showing.

.single-senators .content article .entry-title, .single-mp .content article .entry-title, .single-districts .content article .entry-title {
    display: none !important;
}

Remove this, and your title should show.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently a `display: none !important` rule in your CSS for the content. If you disable that rule, the text displays. I don't think it displays as you'll want (the image does not show as a left column in any way, which I assume is desired from its class `left-col`), but at least the text starts displaying and gives you a place to begin tweaking from.

Look at the CSS rule for

```
.single-mp .entry-content, .single-senators .entry-content, .single-districts .entry-content { display: none !important; }
```